# Errors when trying to use DQN algorithm for FrozenLake Openai game

Tags: python, machine-learning, openai-gym, ray, rllib

I am trying to make a very simple DQN algorithm work with the FrozenLake-v0 game but I am getting errors. I understand that it could be an overkill using DQN instead of a Q-table, but I nonetheless would like it to work. Here is the code:

```
import gym
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

env = gym.make("FrozenLake-v0")

n_actions = env.action_space.n
input_dim = env.observation_space.n
model = tf.keras.Sequential() 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, input_dim = input_dim , activation = 'relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_actions, activation = 'linear'))
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss = 'mse')

def replay(replay_memory, minibatch_size=32):
    minibatch = np.random.choice(replay_memory, minibatch_size, replace=True)
    s_l =      np.array(list(map(lambda x: x['s'], minibatch)))
    a_l =      np.array(list(map(lambda x: x['a'], minibatch)))
    r_l =      np.array(list(map(lambda x: x['r'], minibatch)))
    sprime_l = np.array(list(map(lambda x: x['sprime'], minibatch)))
    done_l   = np.array(list(map(lambda x: x['done'], minibatch)))
    qvals_sprime_l = model.predict(sprime_l)
    target_f = model.predict(s_l) 
    for i,(s,a,r,qvals_sprime, done) in enumerate(zip(s_l,a_l,r_l,qvals_sprime_l, done_l)): 
        if not done:  target = r + gamma * np.max(qvals_sprime)
        else:         target = r
        target_f[i][a] = target
    model.fit(s_l,target_f, epochs=1, verbose=0)
    return model

n_episodes = 500
gamma = 0.99
epsilon = 0.9
minibatch_size = 32
r_sums = []  
replay_memory = []
mem_max_size = 100000

for n in range(n_episodes): 
    s = env.reset()
    done=False
    r_sum = 0
    print(s)
    while not done: 
        qvals_s = model.predict(s.reshape(16))
        if np.random.random() < epsilon:  a = env.action_space.sample()
        else:                             a = np.argmax(qvals_s); 
        sprime, r, done, info = env.step(a)
        r_sum += r 
        if len(replay_memory) > mem_max_size:
            replay_memory.pop(0)
        replay_memory.append({"s":s,"a":a,"r":r,"sprime":sprime,"done":done})
        s=sprime
        model=replay(replay_memory, minibatch_size = minibatch_size)
    if epsilon > 0.1:      epsilon -= 0.001
    r_sums.append(r_sum)
    if n % 100 == 0: print(n)
```

And the errors I am getting are:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "froz_versuch.py", line 48, in <module>
    qvals_s = model.predict(s.reshape(16))
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (16,)
```

And when I try to then change `qvals_s = model.predict(s.reshape(16))` to `qvals_s = model.predict(s.reshape(1))` I get the error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 16 but received input with shape [None, 1]
```

I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had to do with one-hot encoding. I had to encode `s` and `sprime` so that they had the dimensions `16`. This change in the for loop made it work. The `encode()` function could be moved outside of the loop but I'm just testing now so optimization comes afterward. Here is the solution:

```
 for n in range(n_episodes): 
    ss = env.reset()
    states_total = 16
    data = [[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]]
    def encode(data, states_total):
        targets = np.array(data).reshape(-1)
        return np.eye(states_total)[targets]
    m = encode(data,states_total)
    s = m[ss]
    #print(s)
    #print(len(s))
    done=False
    r_sum = 0
    while not done: 
        #env.render()
        qvals_s = model.predict(s.reshape(1,-1))
        if np.random.random() < epsilon:  a = env.action_space.sample()
        else:                             a = np.argmax(qvals_s); 
        sprime, r, done, info = env.step(a)
        r_sum += r
        q = encode(data,states_total)
        sprime = q[sprime]
        if len(replay_memory) > mem_max_size:
            replay_memory.pop(0)
        replay_memory.append({"s":s,"a":a,"r":r,"sprime":sprime,"done":done})
        #s = n[sprime]
        s=sprime
        model=replay(replay_memory, minibatch_size = minibatch_size)
    if epsilon > 0.001:      epsilon -= 0.001
    r_sums.append(r_sum)
    print(r_sum)
    print(epsilon)
    if n % 100 == 0: print(n)
```